# How many clicks are too many?

Tags: help

We design a Help window for a mobile application. Ideally, how many clicks should be there before user reach the Help.

Comment: Hi Mrini, welcome to UX.se! Right now, the answer to your question is 'One'. If you provide more context you will get a better answer. What is the app about? What does it do? What cases require a help window? etc.

Comment: Welcome Mrini, but have you even tried [googling](https://www.google.nl/search?q=How+many+clicks+are+too+many%3F) for this? There are plenty of articles out there that can help you determine this.

Comment: Also, [How Many Clicks for Given Action?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4258/how-many-clicks-for-given-action) on this site may be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is the number of the 'clicks' does not matter. It is the quality of the 'clicks' that matter. If there are 20 steps but they are very clear it is better than 5 steps that are really difficult for the user to see and understand.

Comment: you definitely don't want to click 20 times to a simple need like help. Number of clicks matter and that is why in the usability matrix, number of clicks is one assessment criteria to user experience.

Comment: I've never heard of 'the usability matrix' - it sounds like it's an attempt to but distinct values on things that are naturally subjective. The aim, of course, is always to create apparent simplicity, but that simplicity cannot be boiled down to the number of clicks. If something takes three clicks but those clicks are confusing and hard to misunderstand then that number is a poor indication of usability. Conversely a good system may indeed take 20 clicks to reach a goal if those 20 clicks take the user forward in the right way. Don't use clicks as a core metric for usability.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide context my answer is broader. You can use [5 whys technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys) to **re-think your app UX and eliminate need of help**.

The example of 5 Whys session could be:

1. *Why* user need help [in particular case]?
   *Because* user doesn't go to the next step.
2. *Why* user doesn't go to the next step?
   *Because* he doesn't see the Next button.
3. *Why* user doesn't see the Next button?
   *Because* the Next button is not perceived as control.
4. *Why* the Next button is not perceived as control?
   *Because* of the button's visual design.
5. *How* can I re-design the button to make it more affordable?
   And this is narrow UX problem you can solve!